# Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client and WorkItems

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Is it possible to manage (create, change state, remove) project WorkItems from TEE CLC?

Looking at help and options, it doesn't seem possible, but eclipse version and SDK clearly make it possible.

A pointer to a doc would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify the scenario? The web interface can be used from any modern browser. If you are looking for automating, then consider the Java Object Model API.

Comment: I'd like not to expand the discussion away from the question. I need to manage workitems from cmd line. TEE CLC sounded like a solution, and this question was specific - can it be done or not? As suggested by CECE - MSFT - tfpt sounds like a most feasible solution as long as I can require Windows&VS installation.

Comment: You may submit a uservoice at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, command lines for managing Work items we are using are [witadmin destroywi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?TrackId=1443c049775c475d9eb21bad114f0034) (destroy work items) and [tfpt workitem](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) (create or update work item). But, witadmin command-line tool installs with any version of Visual Studio, and tfpt workitem command-line tool installs with TFS power tools which works with VS client. Neither of them supports Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client.

I'm afraid there is no Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client command for managing work items.

Comment: Hey! This not only answers the question, but also raises the question if I really need TEE CLC (non-Win/VS environment).

Comment: With tftp, how do you achieve automation (skip login dialog)? Is it enough that user (local or domain) running tfpt has tfpt permissions?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still focused on workitems. I've created an account X, and added it to project team. Logged in as X, and running tfpt workitem (providing /location:) worked without login dialog. I wonder if this will work with domain accounts as well.

Answer (score 0):

As CeCe writes, there isn't any cross-platform tool to managed work items similar to witadmin or tfpt.  Also, the TEE CLC uses the TFS SDK for Java but the CLC is packaged up in the download for convenience.  There should not be a dependency between the plugin and the CLC.

Comment: "There should not be a dependency between the plugin and the CLC." Which plugin are you referring to?

Comment: Eclipse plugin? So, there is no dep between the plugin and CLC, but they surely both depend on SDK. Since CLC doesn't support workitem management, I might write a SDK based tool in java. I surely wouldn't be considering that if there was an obscure option in CLC.